# How to draw a line under the title cells on TDBGrid using C++ in Rad Studio?

Tags: c++, user-interface, delphi

I am trying to draw a line under TDBGrid title cells but can't seem to get it to work. I am doing this in the OnDrawColumnCell event like this:

```
   Canvas->Pen->Color = TColor(RGB(0, 0, 0));
   Canvas->MoveTo(Rect.Left, Rect.Bottom);
   Canvas->LineTo(Rect.Right, Rect.Bottom);
```

It's signature looks like this:

```
void __fastcall TfrmModelDetails::dbGridModelMapDrawColumnCell(TObject *Sender, const TRect &Rect,
          int DataCol, TColumn *Column, TGridDrawState State)
```

I am sure that the method is being called after checking the debug information yet nothing gets drawn. Why could this be?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`OnDrawColumnCell` is not called for title cells. As far as I can see in `TCustomDBGrid` source code, title drawing is done by an inner procedure you can't change from the outside. Probably you have to derive a new component and override `DrawCell` which does all the processing.

You didn't show your complete code for `dbGridModelMapDrawColumnCell`... Be sure to call `DefaultDrawColumnCell` in front of it and then do your own drawing.

Also, the last pixel line is `Rect.Bottom - 1`. You are drawing out of view.

And finally, `Canvas` alone refers to the form, not the grid. You have to either qualify with the `DBGrid` instance you use or cast the `Sender` argument to `TDBGrid` to refer to it's `Canvas` property.

Comment: Thanks for the tips. Casting Sender to DBGrid helped out to get the lines drawing. However I am trying to get the line to draw under the title cells. I get the row number and use it to determine whether I need the line there. The problem is that whenever I add a new line to the grid it considers it as row no. 1 even if it is at the end of the grid. Is there any other way to determine if the line being drawn is first in the whole grid or not?

Comment: @KapitaiN You have not fully read my answer... When the title line is draw, the event OnDrawColumnCell is not called. The drawing routine is hardcoded as an inner procedure you can override and having no event attached. So your only (IMO) solution is to derive a new component and override DrawCell which does all the processing.

Comment: Ahhhh ok. I get it now. Thanks!